# The "d" Custom Format Specifier - not working

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dSpecifier) for how the "d" Custom Format Specifier is supposed to work:

**Consider this code:**

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));
// Should result in 8
// Result I'm seeing is 08/07/2014
```

Why is the "d" not working?

Comment: If you want the day, why not just use `DateTime.Now.Day`

Comment: @tnw - I could do that, but I want to test the ToString method by passing it different DateTime format specifiers at runtime to see what results come up.

Comment: did you read the documentation you linked?  Your question is explicitly addressed

Comment: @Jonesy - nope...just made an assumption that it would work - silly me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the documentation, notice the first sentence:

> **If the "d" format specifier is used without other custom format specifiers, it is interpreted as the "d" standard date and time format specifier.** For more information about using a single format specifier, see [Using Single Custom Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) later in this topic.